# compile error in test class

Tags: unit-test

```
@isTest
private class methodonetest {
    private static Account acc;
        private static Opportunity  Opp;
        private static Quote  Q;
        private static Product2 prd;
        private static QuoteLineItem Qli;

    @testSetup static void testData(){

        acc = new Account();
        acc.Name = 'TestAccount';
        insert acc; 

        Opp = new Opportunity(Name=acc.Name + ' Opportunity ',

                                       StageName='Prospecting',start_date__c = system.today(),end_date__c = system.today()+45,

                                       CloseDate=System.today().addMonths(3),

                                       AccountId=acc.Id);

        insert Opp;

        prd = new product2(name='unittestproduct');

        prd.Family = 'License';

        insert prd;

       Pricebook2 stdPb = [select Id,name, isactive from Pricebook2 where IsStandard = true limit 1];
       //Id t = Test.getStandardPricebookId();
        //insert stdPb;
        PricebookEntry pbe = new PricebookEntry(pricebook2id = stdPb.Id, product2id = prd.id,unitprice=1.0,isActive=true);
        insert pbe;
         q=new quote(name='myquotetest',opportunityid=opp.id,pricebook2id=stdPb.Id, status='Draft');
        insert q;
        quoteLineItem i = new quotelineitem(); 
        i.quoteid      = q.id; 
        i.pricebookentryid    = pbe.id; 
        i.quantity            = 1; 
        i.unitprice           = 1; 
              insert i; 


    }
    @istest(SeeAllData=true)
    static void testApexPageMessages(){
        Test.startTest();

         //CreateOrderFromQuote s = new CreateOrderFromQuote();    
        CreateOrderFromQuote.UpdateStatusField(q.Id);
        Test.stopTest();
    }
}
```

This is my test class.
I'm getting the error:

> Test class containing a test setup method cannot have any methods
>   annotated with @isTest(​SeeAllData=​true)

I need seeattdata=true as i;m using standard pricebbok2.
can someone help me how to solve the issue?

Comment: This situation is exactly as error says. Hence why don't you setup the required test data without the @testSetup annotation. If it is governor limits for the actual test that you are worried about, then test.startTest and test.stopTest can give you a fresh context just for testing out the logic.

Comment: You also do not need to use SeeAllData = true , to test logic related to pricebooks. We can set it up along with test data. Please see official release notes - https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/summer14/release-notes/rn_apex_price_books_in_tests.htm

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to this [link](https://developer.salesforce.com/releases/release/Spring15/TestClasses)

> Test Setup Method Considerations
>
> Test setup methods are supported only with the default data isolation
>   mode for a test class. If the test class or a test method has access
>   to organization data by using the @isTest(SeeAllData=true) annotation,
>   test setup methods aren’t supported in this class.

So either remove the annotation of @testsetup and call your static method in the test method or try and do the test without the SeeAllData attribute